# ESP 32 Flash Download Tool showing SPIFFS partition not found

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

I have created a custom code for ESp32 in Arduino IDE. I flashed the program directly from IDE using UART with the help of TTL. I'm looking for an alternative method to flash the firmware of ESP32.
I'm trying to flash the esp32 binary file generated from Arduino IDE, using the flash downloader tool.

https://www.espressif.com/en/support/download/other-tools

I have used the configuration settings as follows

[image: Flash Configuration settings]

This settings flashed the  firmware and the board reset worked perfectly. The SPIFFS did not however work.

*Please find the log attached.*

[image: SPIFFS Failure Log]

*Also  attached the reset log after flashing for reference*

[image: Boot log reset]

Thanks for the help.